# 2 monitors, 1 tv with HD 7870

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors

I'm planning on buying a [Radeon HD 7870](http://www.amd.com/us/products/desktop/graphics/7000/7870/pages/radeon-7870.aspx#1) soon and I want to check if my desired setup is possible.

I want two monitors and one TV with three separate desktops/images on each. I do not want any of this eyefinity-stretching the same image over multiple monitors.

For example I want to be able to have my IDE maximized on one screen, while having the website I'm working on maximized on the other screen. The TV is there for when I want to watch anything on it and not having to change any cables or the like.

The card has one dvi, two display ports and one hdmi port, so I'm guessing the TV goes into the hdmi while the monitors goes to the display ports.

Will this work out-of-the-box? Do I need an active display port adapter? Do I have to use eyefinity and is it possible to use it as described above without the stretching?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will work out of the box, the 2 DVIs and HDMI are all digital. You do NOT need any adapters. You can also setup the non stretch desktop. All your needs are handled by any OS by default these days, be it Windows or Linux.

Considering the Radeon HD 7870 has an audio input, once you hook your audio on your Graphics card, the HDMI will output sound and display to ur TV. This might disable the sound on your speakers / headphones when sound is coming of the TV Speakers